# Rails activeRecord version for to_tsvector() function of Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5, tsvector

I have a TSVECTOR column in my database and I want to update this column via Rails callback rather than a trigger. I want to know if there's an ActiveRecord code to achieve this. So far I'm doing this by manually executing a raw SQL and it doesn't look nice.

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("update my_table set tsvector_document = to_tsvector('english', #{string_tokens}) where id = #{id}")
```

I'm wondering if there's a better approach to do this without using a raw SQL.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's guaranteed to perform worse (extra client-server round trip). Why do you want such a column rather than an expression index on the underlying data?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe could you elaborate on that? that column is a combination of diff data from different models. I use it for searching and I need the features of a tsvector column to achieve the searching behavior needed.

Comment: If the column contains data from different tables, you really need it, as. you cannot have a single index on multiple tables. Still, I think that a trigger is the correct solution for such requirements, as it runs in the same transaction as the data modifying statements, so that consistency is guaranteed automatically. Only consider alternatives if you have (ill-guided) strict requirements not to use PostgreSQL as a database, but to abuse it as a key-value store.

Comment: The reason why I did not consider the trigger at first is due to possible performance issues. But I'll reconsider using it now. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using rails' PG Search plugin for this where it handles this TS Vector conversion.

```
PgSearch.multisearch_options = {
  using: {
    tsearch: {
      prefix: true,
      dictionary: 'english',
      tsvector_column: 'vector_column_name_here'
    },
    trigram: {
      threshold: 0.2
    }
  }
}
```